# Failed alloc mem to rom during installation

Tags: boot

i'm trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 on a Acer Aspire 10, and when i select install Ubuntu a series of "failed to alloc mem to rom" appear, and then Just a Black screen Forever

What Can i do?

Comment: I would suggest installing a supported version of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 17.04 was released in 2017-April (hence its version number) with nine months of support which ended 13-Jan-2018 thus it's EOL (end-of-life).  Use a LTS version of Ubuntu if you want 5 years of support, or use the later 17.10 (October release)

Comment: @guiverc I'm having the same problem with the same Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.

I had to disable Secure Boot by taking a lot of steps, just to get to GRUB and now this happens.

I'm getting rid of this piece of garbage

Don't buy this Acer Laptops. You might think American companies don't like Linux. The Chinese manufacturers don't like Linux even more. 

They sometimes even violate GPL without any consequences. Don't buy chinese $17

Comment: I solved by formatting all and reinstalling windows, after that i disabled automatic updates and buyed a micro sd, now it's fine. Windows updatas are just a danger